# Replacing characters of string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am replacing the character and/or string in l3 by comparing it with l1 and l2 . What output I am getting and what output I like to get is shown below.

my code

```
l1 = ["Jai","Sharath","Ravi","Aditya"]
l2 = ["Singh","Kumar","Sharma","Rao"]
l3 = ["J.Singh","Sharath_K","R-Sharma","Rao_Aditya"]
for x,y,z in zip(l1,l2,l3):
  if x in z:
    z.replace(x,"Firstname")
  elif x[0] in z:
    z.replace(x[0],"First/Character/of/first/name")
  elif y in z:
    z.replace(y,"lastname")
  else:
    z.replace(y[0],"First/Character/of/last/name")
```

my output

```
'First/Character/of/first/name.Singh'
'Firstname_K'
'First/Character/of/first/name/Sharma'
'Rao_Firstname'
```

my expected output

```
'First/Character/of/first/name.lastname'
'Firstname_First/Character/of/last/name'
'First/Character/of/first/name/lastname'
'lastname_Firstname'
```

how do i get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable. `replace` does not work in-place, it returns a new string. You need to reallocate that new string to the original name.

```
if x in z:
    z = z.replace(x,"Firstname")
```

(Also, please use more than one space indentation.)

Comment: what other way can i use

Comment: Why do you want another way? What's wrong with this one?

Comment: then how do i include the last 2 conditions

Comment: if i use the above code only output for last value is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Consider your use of `elif`.  If your first condition triggers, replacing the first name, will the last condition trigger to replace the last name?  You may want to try two `if` `else` structures.

Consider the following:

```
z = 'abc'
if z[0] == 'a':
    z = z.replace('a', '1')
elif z[1] == 'b':
    z = z.replace('b', '2')
if z[2] == 'c':
    z = z.replace('c', '3')
```

What will z be at the end of this block?  Would removing the `z =` change that?  How does changing the conditionals (`if` `elif` `else`) change the output?

Comment: i get two instances of output if i use the above code

Comment: And also its impractical to compare character by character if the list size is 100+